# HMAC SQL Server to MySQL function

Tags: mysql, sql-server, amazon-web-services, hmac

I've been trying to sign a signature 4 payload and for various reasons I'm unable to use one of the AWS SDKs.  I've done it before by calling the below SQL Server Function, but I have to do it this time in MySQL.

How can I convert this SQL Server function to MySQL?  I've tried myself and I've tried a few online converters. Unfortunately I've run out of time trying to learn MySQL well enough to figure it out.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION HMAC (
    p_algo VARCHAR(20)
    ,p_key LONGBLOB
    ,p_data LONGBLOB
    )
    /* This function only takes VARBINARY parameters instead of VARCHAR
to prevent problems with implicit conversion from NVARCHAR to VARCHAR 
which result in incorrect hashes for inputs including non-ASCII characters. 
Always cast @key and @data parameters to VARBINARY when using this function. 
Tested against HMAC vectors for MD5 and SHA1 from RFC 2202 */

/*
List of secure hash algorithms (parameter @algo) supported by MSSQL 
version. This is what is passed to the HASHBYTES system function.
Omit insecure hash algorithms such as MD2 through MD5
2005-2008R2: SHA1 
2012-2016: SHA1 | SHA2_256 | SHA2_512 
*/
RETURNS VARBINARY(64)
BEGIN
    DECLARE v_ipad BIGINT;
    DECLARE v_opad BIGINT;
    DECLARE v_i VARBINARY(64);
    DECLARE v_o VARBINARY(64);
    DECLARE v_pos INTEGER;

    -- SQL 2005 only allows XOR operations on integer types, so use bigint and interate 8 times
    SET v_ipad = cast(0x3636363636363636 AS BIGINT); -- constants from HMAC definition
    SET v_opad = cast(0x5C5C5C5C5C5C5C5C AS BIGINT);

    IF char_length(rtrim(p_key)) > 64 THEN -- if the key is grater than 512 bits we hash it first per HMAC definition
        SET p_key = cast(hashbytes(p_algo, p_key) AS BINARY (64));
    ELSE
        SET p_key = cast(p_key AS BINARY (64));
    END IF; -- otherwise pad it out to 512 bits with zeros

    SET v_pos = 1;
    SET v_i = cast('' AS VARBINARY(64)); -- initialize as empty binary value

    WHILE v_pos <= 57
    DO
        SET v_i = v_i + cast((substring(p_key, v_pos, 8) ^; v_ipad) AS VARBINARY(64))
        SET v_pos = v_pos + 8;
    END WHILE;

    SET v_pos = 1;
    SET v_o = cast('' AS VARBINARY(64)); -- initialize as empty binary value

    WHILE v_pos <= 57
    DO
        SET v_o = v_o + cast((substring(p_key, v_pos, 8) ^; v_opad) AS VARBINARY(64))
        SET v_pos = v_pos + 8;
    END WHILE;

    RETURN hashbytes(p_algo, v_o + hashbytes(p_algo, v_i + p_data));
END;
//

DELIMITER ;




GRANT EXECUTE
    ON HMAC
    TO PUBLIC;


/*
Copyright © 2012 Ryan Malayter. All Rights Reserved. 
Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without 
modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are 
met: 
1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright 
notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer. 
2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright 
notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the 
documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution. 
3. The name of the author may not be used to endorse or promote products 
derived from this software without specific prior written permission. 
THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY Ryan Malayter "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR 
IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED 
WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE 
DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHOR BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, 
INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES 
(INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR 
SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) 
HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, 
STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN 
ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE 
POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE. 
*/
```

Comment: Questions requesting the conversion of a whole piece of code are too broad for Stack Overflow. It is much better to give the conversion a go yourself, and then show where _specifically_ you are stuck, and what research you have done on it. That is much likely to get answers too, since readers see that you have exerted personal effort.

Comment: I wonder also whether this is too application-oriented to do in a stored procedure - consider doing it in your application code instead.